# Why two smtpd.py are installed?

Tags: python

After installing python on Linux, smtpd.py will be installed under /usr/bin directory. Why does this module exist here? How about the other one under directory /usr/lib/python2.x? What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The one in `/usr/bin` is in your `PATH` and can be executed by calling its filename in a shell.

The second one is in library directory referenced by `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path` and can be used as a module in python scripts.

They are probably hard or symlinks if they have the same content.

Comment: I just wonder why smtpd.py is special enough to be installed under /usr/bin directory. Who need to call this script directly in shell? Why not other modules under /usr/lib/python2.x?

Comment: @shinningstar You should ask that to your distro package mantainer.